# How to apply validation on image in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

User can only insert image in image field.

I tried this validation in my method

```
string[] allowedExtensions = { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png" };

var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(model.PhotoPath.FileName);

if (!allowedExtensions.Any(ext => String.Equals(ext, fileExtension, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("PhotoPath", "Allowed file types are .jpg, .jpeg, .png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check the actual content type of the file.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadImage(ImageModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Check if a file was uploaded
            if (model.PhotoPath != null && model.PhotoPath.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                // Get the file extension
                string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(model.PhotoPath.FileName);
    
                // Allowed file extensions
                string[] allowedExtensions = { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png" };
    
                // Check if the file extension is allowed
                if (!allowedExtensions.Any(ext => String.Equals(ext, fileExtension, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("PhotoPath", "Allowed file types are .jpg, .jpeg, .png");
                }
                else
                {
                    // Check the content type of the file
                    string contentType = model.PhotoPath.ContentType;
                    if (!contentType.StartsWith("image/"))
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("PhotoPath", "Invalid content type. Only images are allowed.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // File is valid, you can save it or process it further
                        // Example: Save the file to a specific location
                        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"), model.PhotoPath.FileName);
                        model.PhotoPath.SaveAs(path);
    
                        // Your logic for saving the image goes here
    
                        // Redirect or return a success message
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("PhotoPath", "Please select a file to upload.");
            }
        }
    
        // If the model state is not valid, return to the view with error messages
        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one -

```
string[] allowedExtensions = { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png" };
var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(model.PhotoPath.FileName);

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileExtension) || !allowedExtensions.Any(ext => ext.Equals(fileExtension, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("PhotoPath", "Please upload a file with a .jpg, .jpeg, or .png extension.");
}
```